# Calling saveEventually on different objects - are they saved in the same order?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I use saveEventually in my Parse powered app where I can so that if connectivity is an issue my app still functions as expected.

I see in the docs it says you can call saveEventually on a single object a number of times, and the save operations are queued in the order they are called.

I have a situation where I need to save one object, then another. Can I rely on these operations being queued in this case also, so that the second object is always saved after the first? Will it continue to queue correctly if I have 100 objects and call saveEventually one-by-one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not always**. They are not guaranteed to save in the same order, but you can always do something like this to ensure that object2 is saved after object1.

```
[object1 saveEventually:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    [object2 saveEventually];
}];
```

Or something like:

```
[object1 saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    [object2 saveInBackground];
}];
```

Comment: The only problem is that if the `saveEventually` call doesn't complete before the app is terminated, it will try again next time the app is run, but WITHOUT the success block, so `object2` might never get saved.

Comment: @TimothyWalters That sounds like a serious problem. Where did you hear that? Also, do you know of any solution?

Comment: It was on the old help forums, but if you think about it there's no support to fully save state of something like that after an app has been closed. The completion block should only be used to update UI, and should not contain further core logic for `saveEventually`, the alternative is to use `saveInBackground` with your own retry logic and persisting the objects yourself to be able to try again if you can't complete it before app restart.